# How can I write adler32 in asm (64 Bit linux asm)?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I tried many times but i have problem on using division, help me pls.
Here is my code:

```
    segment .bss
s   resb 8

    segment .data
fp  db "/usr/share/diet/words"

    segment .text
    global main
    global adler32
    extern printf
    extern stdlib   
    extern fopen
    extern fgets

    ; long adler32(char *data, int len)

adler32:
.data   equ 0
.len    equ 8
.i  equ 16

    push  rbp
    mov   rbp,rsp
    sub   rsp,32
    mov   [rsp+.data],rdi
    mov   [rsp+.len],rsi
    xor   rcx,rcx
    mov   [rsp+.i],rcx 

    segment .data
.a  dq    1
.b  dq    0
.const  dd    65521

    segment .text
.loop

    mov   rcx,[rsp+.i]
    cmp   rcx,[rsp+.len]
    je    .end

    ;for ( i = 0 ; i < len ; i++ ) {
    ;   a = (a + data [i] ) % 65521 ;
    ;   b = (b + a) % 65521 ;
    ;}
    ;return (b <<16) | a

    mov   rdi,[rsp+.data]       ; rdi = (data)
    add   rdi,rcx           ; rdi = (data+i)
    mov   rdi,[rdi]         ; rdi = *(data +i)
    add   rdi,0         ; convert char to number

    mov   rax,[.a]          ; save a
    add   rax,rdi           ; a = a+data[i]
    xor   rdx,rdx
    idiv  [.const]          ; a = a%65521, 
    mov   [.a],rdx          ; save a

    mov   rax,[.b]          ; save b
    add   rax,rdx           ; b = b + a
    xor   rdx,rdx
    idiv  [.const]          ; b = b%65521, 
    mov   [.b],rdx          ; save b

    inc   rcx
    mov   [rsp+.i],rcx
    jmp   .loop

.end

    mov   rax,[.b]
    shl   rax,16
    mov   rdx,[.a]
    or    rax,rdx

    leave
    ret

main:
    push  rbp
    mov   rbp,rsp

    ; file *fp = fopen(char *file_name,char mode)

    lea   rdi,[fp]
    mov   rsi,'r'
    call  fopen

    ; char *fgets(char *s,int size,FILE *fp)

    mov   rdi,s
    mov   rsi,16
    mov   rdx,rax
    call  fgets

    mov  rdi,rax
    mov  rsi,16
    call adler32

    leave
    ret
```

Comment: code-golf [Compute the Adler-32 checksum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78972) in 32 bytes of x86-64 code.  (But that's not a good example to follow because it's opimized for size at the expense of speed using the `loop` instruction and other nasty stuff.)

Comment: Use `cqo` instead of xor-zeroing to set up for signed `idiv`.

Comment: This probably doesn't assemble because you left out the `qword` size specifier for the memory operand for `idiv`.  Put the value in a register instead of loading it from memory every time.  I assume that your problem, but this isn't a [mcve].  (missing any error messages.)